# Where to buy 2005 Shimano 105/Ultegra brifter hoods?

Tags: maintenance, shimano, parts, shifter

I have a [2005 Trek 1500 WSD](http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2005&brand=Trek&model=1500%20WSD) road bike with original Shimano 105 STI brake/shifter levers.  I'm looking for replacement hoods for the brifters because the originals are wearing out.

I believe the groupset model number is ST-5510.  I also believe that ST-5500, ST-6500, and ST-6510 hoods should all be compatible (55xx = 105, 65xx = Ultegra, xx10 = Flight Deck).

Can anyone point me to a source to buy a pair of hoods for these levers?  I've searched and searched and come up empty handed.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but any 9-speed Shimano road shifters would be compatible with your shifters. For example I've obtained 6500 parts, and also have a bike with a 9-speed 4500 Tiagra groupset, and don't seem to have problems sourcing these parts. Now I realise your asking about hoods as opposed to the full shifter, but maybe the hoods will be compatible? I don't know if they are or not but maybe it gives you another avenue down which to search.

Comment: The Tiagra hoods are not compatible unfortunately.  105 and Ultegra back then were pretty much the same, but Tiagra has a different shape.  I could buy the entire shifters, but that seems wasteful--the 105 levers are no worse than anything I'd replace them with.

Comment: Only a comment but I had some on an Ultegra from 1990 that were drying out and lathered them up with Armor All and brought em back to life.

Comment: eBay is awash with 105 replacement hoods.

Answer (score 1):

My hoods were degrading too causing me to get black rubber on my hands after every ride.

I called Shimano and they said that they no longer support the ST-5500 lever and they do not carry any replacement parts.

I called Hudz, and they said that they do not have hoods that are compatible.

A STOPGAP SOLUTION: Rub your hoods with baby powder. It makes them much less sticky, and no more black residue.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around, it sounds like Shimano and other companies who do hoods may have discontinued them - it may be useful to shoot Shimano an email to see if this is true.

I'd check your bike shop/co-op's parts bin - theres a good chance one of those shifters from a wreck is in there, which you can salvage the hoods from.

Alternatively, if you go to a bike shop, they might be able to pull it up in the QBP catalog (part CA-5500 or something is what the internet tells me).

Comment: CA-5500 seems to be the part number for the entire brifter.  But searching for that brings up the parts list: http://bike.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/ev/bikecomponents/st/ev-st-5500-ca-1934b_v1_m56577569830612179.pdf which shows "Y-6B9 98090" as the part number for the pair of hoods.  Sadly I live in a place with not a whole lot of well-stocked bike shops, but I'll try contacting Shimano.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, even if your bike shop isn't well stocked, chances are they're buying from QBP. So they should have access to the QBP catalog and if possible be able to order it.

Comment: I contacted Shimano directly.  They say these parts are no longer available.  That's not very nice--the groupset is ten years old which seems like a perfect time to be selling spares for it, and it's not like we're talking about some low-end parts here.